# Python- Function which returns the average mark

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to create a function which returns the average of a student's module. The student's data is stored in a list which contains the following, so Dave has: `('Dave', 0, 'none', 'M106', ['50'])`
and then Ollie has: `('Ollie', 'M104', 0, 'none', ['60'])`. I can't get my head around how to get the average from the two averages.

```
def moduleAverage(self):
    if student.getAverage is > 0:

    return self.moduleAverage
```

Comment: What is `is >`?

Comment: If you had two numbers would you know how to get the average? If you had a string representing a number do you know how to convert it to an integer (or float). If you have a list (or tuple) with multiple elements do you know how to get the value of the element you want?

Comment: > is greater than? student is a class from another file which contains the list of student details (it contains there name the course, average mark etc) but what im trying to get this function to do is to work out the average of all the students averages.

Comment: do you have some kind of student class? or just tuples? is student just a list of tuples?

Comment: What is a student module?

Answer (score 0):

Ok first I have to say: Correct your indentation.
So I'll make a little example now:

```
studentDetails = []
studentDetails.append(('Peter', ['40']))
studentDetails.append(('Frank', ['100']))
studentDetails.append(('Ernest', ['40']))

def moduleAverage(inList):
    total = 0.0
    for i in xrange(0, len(inList)):
        total += float(inList[i][1][0]) # the score is at the index 1 in the tuple (('Peter', ['40']))

    return (total / float(len(inList)))

print moduleAverage(studentDetails)
```

Pay attention: You have the single mark ['40'] as a string, so you have to convert it to float.
Also remain the same order in the student tuple.
I don't know your whole structure so I just made a simple example of the algorithm with tuples as you mentioned in your question.